# Sum values inside the itertools.combinations Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, python-itertools

I have this dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

A= ['ABC', 'DEF'] 
M= ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
F= ['plus', 'minus', 'star']

# Create all possible permutation from <A,M,F> 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(A,M,F)), columns=['A', 'M', 'F'])
df['value'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, df.shape[0])
```

Data set looks like:

```
     A  M   F        value
0   ABC X   plus    0.666602
1   ABC X   minus   0.716765
2   ABC X   star    0.032931
3   ABC Y   plus    0.275616
4   ABC Y   minus   0.489233
```

In here I want to get top-k combination of sets which maximizes my goal:

`My goal is : The maximum of Sum(values of combination sets) + sum(distance of combination sets)`

This is my code:

```
#diversity/distance function
def diversity(a, b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    d = float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))
    return 1 - d
```

My code:

```
from itertools import combinations

k = 3

max_distance = []

# I drop the column 'value' because sets that I want to compare is <A,M,F>
df_distance = df.drop(['value'],axis=1)
series_set = df_distance.apply(lambda row: set(row), axis=1)
data = series_set

for z in combinations(data, k):
    dis = 0
    sum_values = 0
    for a in combinations(z, 2):
        dis += diversity(*a)
        # I am stuck here, I want to sum the value but I don't know, how to get the value and sum it in combination
    max_distance.append((dis, tuple(z)))

max_distance.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(max_distance[:k])
```

The output:

```
[(2.8, ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Y', 'minus', 'ABC'}, {'Z', 'star', 'DEF'})), (2.8, ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Y', 'star', 'ABC'}, {'Z', 'minus', 'DEF'})), (2.8, ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Z', 'minus', 'ABC'}, {'Y', 'star', 'DEF'}))]
```

In my code above, I just compute the sum of distance. The value 2.8 is just sum of distance. I want to sum the distance among sets but only from columns[A,M,F], and I also want to sum the values. The expected output is the (sum of distance + sum of value) which optimum of all combinations of sets.

I am really stuck in how to sum the values inside the combination?

Expected output:

```
  [(sum(distance) + sum(values) , ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Y', 'minus', 'ABC'}, {'Z', 'star', 'DEF'})), ((sum(distance) + sum(values), ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Y', 'star', 'ABC'}, {'Z', 'minus', 'DEF'})), ((sum(distance) + sum(values), ({'plus', 'ABC', 'X'}, {'Z', 'minus', 'ABC'}, {'Y', 'star', 'DEF'}))]
```

Please let me know when you have question, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below a slightly modified version of your code. I *think* its what you were going for. I basically moved your `set` cast into the diversity function so that `series_set` could be a tuple. Then that tuple can be used to slice a DataFrame with a multi-index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product, combinations

A = ['ABC', 'DEF']
M = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
F = ['plus', 'minus', 'star']

# Create all possible permutation from <A,M,F>
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(A,M,F)), columns=['A', 'M', 'F'])
df['value'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, df.shape[0])


# diversity/distance function
def diversity(a, b):
    c = set(a).intersection(b)
    d = float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))
    return 1 - d

k = 3
max_distance = []
max_values = []

# I drop the column 'value' because sets that I want to compare is <A,M,F>
df_distance = df.drop(['value'],axis=1)
df_sum = df.set_index(['A', 'M', 'F'])
series_set = df_distance.apply(lambda row: tuple(row), axis=1)
data = series_set

for z in combinations(data, k):
    dis = 0
    sum_values = 0
    for a in combinations(z, 2):
        dis += diversity(*a)
        sum_values += df_sum.ix[a[0], 'value'] + df_sum.ix[a[1], 'value']
    max_distance.append((dis, tuple(z)))
    max_values.append((sum_values, tuple(z)))

max_distance.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(max_distance[:k])

max_values.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(max_values[:k])
```

-- UPDATE --

```
max_total = []
for z in combinations(data, k):
    dis = 0
    sum_values = 0
    for a in combinations(z, 2):
        dis += diversity(*a)
        sum_values += df_sum.loc[a[0], 'value'] + df_sum.loc[a[1], 'value']
    total_sum = dis + sum_values
    max_total.append((total_sum, tuple(z)))

max_total.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(max_total[:k])
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this answer, but in here I want to `max_total.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)` then `print(max_total[:k)`. I mean the sum values also will be used to decide which combination of sets which has a maximum. The combination which has max total will be the result.

Comment: and it also gives me an error: C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:35: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated

Comment: Hi Ido S Thank you, but if I am not wrong, it seem that the total value is wrong. For example `(8.4226393121550736, (('ABC', 'X', 'plus'), ('DEF', 'Y', 'minus'), ('DEF', 'Z', 'star'))`
`total distance = 2.8 not 8.422 `

`total values = 0.98+0.94+0.88 = 2.8`

`max_total should be : 5.6`

Comment: i used that data that you generated in the post, which seems to be different from the data that you're mentioning here? for this combination im getting ````[(4.8669925765449484,
  (('ABC', 'X', 'plus'), ('DEF', 'Y', 'minus'), ('DEF', 'Z', 'star')))]````. and according to your data table, total values should be ````[0.64515316530289457, 0.58542398144044849, 0.036449070043609644]````, assuming its simply the ````value```` field that corresponds to the tuple row.